# 21.10 unable to see "instances" of nautilus in launcher/dock

Tags: nautilus, launcher

I have a link on my launcher/dock for nautiles/"files".

[image]

When I click on it, an instance of nautilus opens. When I then hover over the button in launcher/dock, I can click on it to show that window of nautilus again.

[image: not very good to see, but you can catch the slightly different background]

When I click any other window, the reference to the already opened nautilus instance disappears. Thus, when I click on nautilus, it will open a new nautilus instance, instead of bringing back the already opened instance. Super annoying. The only way to get back to my previously opened nautilus is by alt tabbing.

Is this a bug? Or can I tweak the behavior somewhere? Tried to google it, but probably due to lack of correct wording I get nowhere.

But when I then click on any other window, the "on hover" effect no longer works.

Comment: In "When I click any other window, this disappears.", what is "this" precisely? Please clarify a bit (use "edit" to change your question)

Comment: @vanadium Tried to explain it better, hope it helps